# why does this namespace resolve correctly?

Tags: c#

I am just looking at a project and I'm seeing something working which I didn't think should work.

If you look at the snippet below I'm in the namespace `CustomFields.DateTimeField.Drivers`, and the only other `using` statements in that file are other namespaces *below* `CustomFields.DateTimeField`.

But if you look on the `public class DateTimeFieldDriver` line it is using a type `Fields.DateTimeField`.

Looking at the definition of `DateTimeField` thats in the namespace `CustomFields.DateTimeField.Fields` but I have only set usings for its sister namespaces.

So the question is twofold - why does this work? is this considered a bad practice?

Snippet in question:

```
using System;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using Orchard;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers;
using Orchard.Localization;

using CustomFields.DateTimeField.Settings;
using CustomFields.DateTimeField.ViewModels;

namespace CustomFields.DateTimeField.Drivers {

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class DateTimeFieldDriver : ContentFieldDriver<Fields.DateTimeField> {

        public IOrchardServices Services { get; set; }

        private const string TemplateName = "Fields/Custom.DateTime"; // EditorTemplates/Fields/Custom.DateTime.cshtml

        public DateTimeFieldDriver(IOrchardServices services) {

            Services = services;
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        }
```

The project can be [downloaded here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Attachments/Creating-a-custom-field-type/CustomFields.zip) if you want to investigate it (MVC2 project).

Comment: Perhaps you should check to see what does the MSDN have to say on the subject? I would guess that some sort of a cascaded search is used to resolve the namespace. I wouldn't say it is bad practice, but having a class with the same name as a parent namespace (`DateTimeField`) definitely counts as not so good/safe to be tried at home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare code to be inside a particular namespace, for example, `CustomFields.DateTimeField.Drivers`, you are *implicitly* importing all the "parent" namespaces as well.

In this case, you have an implied using for `CustomFields` and `CustomFields.DateTimeField`.  This is why you do not have to specify an explicit `using` statement for types in `CustomFields.DateTimeField` and furthermore, for *subnamespaces* contained therein.

Thus `Fields.DateTimeField` is found by combining `CustomFields.DateTimeField` (the implied namespace) with `Fields.DateTimeField` (the explicit namespace) to resolve to `CustomFields.DateTimeField.Fields.DateTimeField`.

And no, as far as I know this is not considered bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, when you're within a namespace, you have implicit `using` for each of the parent namespaces. For example in this file:

```
using System;

namespace Foo.Bar.Baz {

    class Qux {
    }
}
\EOF
```

Is the same as this file:

```
using System;

using Foo;
using Foo.Bar;

namespace Foo.Bar.Baz {

    class Qux {
    }
}
\EOF
```

If you have a namespace imported, then you don't need to specify the full namespace to access members of a sibling namespace tree provided it has the same prefix as an imported namespace:

```
using Foo;
using Foo.Bar;

namespace Foo.Bar.Baz {

    class Qux {
    }
}

namespace Foo.Bar.Norf {

    class Guf : Bar.Baz.Qux { // namespace `Foo.` is implicitly assumed to prefix the namespace reference `Bar.Baz`
    }
}
\EOF
```

You're experiencing these two effects combined: implicit namespace prefix usage to an implicitly imported namespace.

As for "bad practice" - experienced C# developers will be familiar with this nuance, but generally it isn't a problem unless you have ambiguous names.

As a tip, try to minimize the number of namespaces and their depths. For example, in your case I see you're storing DateTime-specific stuff in its own `DateTimeField` namespace. This has a bad "code smell" to me. I would just put everything in the `CustomFields` namespace, especially as you've given each typename the prefix `DateTime` anyway, so it's just double-typing.

FxCop will complain if you have fewer than 5 types in a namespace too, btw.

Update: I took a look at the C# specification ( http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf ), section 16, but I can't find any part of it which states that parent namespaces are implicitly imported, which is strange.